# Pandas dataframe of dataframes with hierarchical columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multidimensional-array, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical dataframe I created in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c']])
df_outer = pd.DataFrame(index=range(4), columns=col_index)
print(df_outer)

     0              1          
     a    b    c    a    b    c
 0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
 3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to populate each entry in this data frame with another data frame, for example:

```
inner_names = ['w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
df_inner = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,4), index=inner_names, columns=inner_names)
```

If this is a bad idea, what would be a better way to create some othe easily indexed data structure containing data frames I want to put in the lements of df_outer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit crazy, because need 3 levels in columns and 2 levels in indices and then assign by selecting with [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
np.random.seed(452)

col_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[0,1], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['w', 'x']])
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(2), ['w', 'x']])
df_outer = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_index, index=idx)
print(df_outer)
       0                             1                         
       a         b         c         a         b         c     
       w    x    w    x    w    x    w    x    w    x    w    x
0 w  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1 w  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  x  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

inner_names = ['w', 'x']
df_inner = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,2), index=inner_names, columns=inner_names)
print(df_inner)
          w         x
w -0.182421  0.962712
x -0.118524 -0.784380

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df_outer.loc[idx[0,:], idx[0, 'a', :]]= df_inner.values
print(df_outer)
            0                                  1                         
            a              b         c         a         b         c     
            w         x    w    x    w    x    w    x    w    x    w    x
0 w -0.182421  0.962712  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  x -0.118524  -0.78438  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1 w       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
  x       NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: This certainly works for the restricted case where the inner data frames are all of the same dimensions.  Fortunately, that's the case for my particular application.  Seems like this can't be done easily when the inner data frames are of varying dimensions.